# Why doesnt my for loop work on iterating over a basic object?

Tags: javascript, object

```
user = {
  lastName: "Jones",
  phone: 12345,
  email: "mike@gmail.com",
  name: "Mike"
}

for(i = 0; i < Object.keys(user).length; i++) {
  theKey = Object.keys(user)[i]
  console.log(user.theKey)
}
```

The current output is:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

expected is:

```
Jones
12345
mike@gmail.com
Mike
```

I know there are other ways to do it but I was wondering what my issue was in doing it this way?

```
Object.keys(user)[i]
```

returns

```
lastName
phone
email
name
```

so I dont understand why it would return undefined in the dot notation. What could I do to return the values of this object in this way?

Comment: yes, you might want to use it like this: `user[theKey]`

Answer (score 1):

thereis no such property as 'theKey' in 'user' Object

try this one

```
console.log(user[theKey])
```

[Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can just do Object.values instead of Object.keys, i also think you don't need theKey variable, i think you can just do console.log(Object.values[i])

Comment: I know that is an option but I wanted to use the Object.keys way. but thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.entries to get both the key and the value. You can also you object.Keys but you have to change it a bit. see below.

```
user = {
  lastName: "Jones",
  phone: 12345,
  email: "mike@gmail.com",
  name: "Mike"
}

Object.keys(user).map((e) => console.log(`key=${e}  value=${obj[e]}`));

Object.entries(user).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(`key=${key} value=${value}`));
```